# DTD. Where did i make a mistake?

Tags: java, xml, dom, dtd

I try to parse this xml file with DOM parser and My code return me correct result but in runtime, ErrorHandler call "error" method which print me "error" it mean that I I somewhere made a mistake. I think that my mistake in DTD, but I don't know where.

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration[
<!ELEMENT configuration (font, window, display)+>
<!ELEMENT display (font, window)>
<!ATTLIST display id ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT font (name, size)>
 <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT size (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT window (height, width)>
 <!ELEMENT height (#PCDATA)>
 <!ELEMENT width (#PCDATA)>
]>
<configuration>
 <display id="112">
  <font>
   <name>Arial</name>
   <size>48</size>
  </font>
  <window>
   <height>1080</height>
   <width>1920</width>
  </window> 
 </display>
 <display id="2893">
  <font>
   <name>ArialBlack</name>
   <size>25</size>
  </font>
  <window>
   <height>480</height>
   <width>640</width>
  </window> 
 </display> 
</configuration>
```

```
public class DisplayConfig {

private static String path;

private String fontName;
private int fontSize;
private int height;
private int width;



public static void setPath(String path) {
    DisplayConfig.path = path;
}

public DisplayConfig(){

}


public DisplayConfig(String fontName, int fontSize, int width, int height) {
    this.fontName = fontName;
    this.fontSize = fontSize;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "[Resolution:" + this.width + "x" + this.height + ", Font:" + this.fontName + ", Font size:" + this.fontSize + "]";
}



public static DisplayConfig getDisplayConfig(int id) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    factory.setValidating(true);
    factory.setIgnoringElementContentWhitespace(true);

    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    builder.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {

        @Override
        public void warning(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("warning");

        }

        @Override
        public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("fatal error");
        }

        @Override
        public void error(SAXParseException exception) throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("error");

        }
    });

    Document document = builder.parse(path);

    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

    NodeList displays = root.getElementsByTagName("display");

    Element display = null;

    for(int i = 0; i<displays.getLength(); i++){
        Element d = (Element) displays.item(i);
        if(Integer.parseInt(d.getAttribute("id")) == id){
            display = d;
            break;
        }
    }

    Element font = (Element) display.getElementsByTagName("font").item(0);
    String fontName = font.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent();
    int fontSize = Integer.parseInt(font.getElementsByTagName("size").item(0).getTextContent());

    Element window = (Element) display.getElementsByTagName("window").item(0);
    int width = Integer.parseInt(window.getElementsByTagName("width").item(0).getTextContent());
    int height = Integer.parseInt(window.getElementsByTagName("height").item(0).getTextContent());

    return new DisplayConfig(fontName, fontSize, width, height);


}
```

}

Comment: `System.out.println(exception);` will give more info about the error.

Answer (score 0):

**Your XML is not valid per its DTD internal subset.**

Make the following changes to make it be valid:

1. Add `font` and `window` elements ahead of `display`, or change the
   content model for `configuration` to not require those elements.  (I
   did the latter below.)
2. Use NCNames (start with letter) for `ID`s or disable namespaces.  (I
   did the former below.)

**Altogether**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration[
<!ELEMENT configuration (display)+>
<!ELEMENT display (font, window)>
<!ATTLIST display id ID #REQUIRED>
<!ELEMENT font (name, size)>
    <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT size (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT window (height, width)>
    <!ELEMENT height (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT width (#PCDATA)>
]>
<configuration>
    <display id="d112">
        <font>
            <name>Arial</name>
            <size>48</size>
        </font>
        <window>
            <height>1080</height>
            <width>1920</width>
        </window>   
    </display>
    <display id="d2893">
        <font>
            <name>ArialBlack</name>
            <size>25</size>
        </font>
        <window>
            <height>480</height>
            <width>640</width>
        </window>   
    </display>  
</configuration>
```